# how to add default elements to `...` when passing those arguments on to another function

Tags: r, function, arguments, parameter-passing

here's a minimal reproducible example of what i want to happen

```
myfun <- 
    function( ... ){

        # myfun only passes `...` on to the plot function
        plot( 
            ... ,
            if( !'xlab' %in% names( list( ... ) ) ) xlab = 'mylabel' ,
            if( !'ylab' %in% names( list( ... ) ) ) ylab = 'ylabel' 
        )
    }

# works the way i want: user specified `xlab` and `ylab` so `...` used them
myfun( 1 , 1 , xlab = "new label" , ylab = "another label" )

# fails
myfun( 1 , 1 )
# Error in plot.window(...) : invalid 'xlim' value
```

since the user did not specify `xlab` and `ylab`, i wanted my function to use the defaults that i have set.  so

```
plot( 1 , 1 , xlab = 'mylabel' , ylab = 'ylabel' )
```

what's the smartest way to do this if i have many possibilities like `xlab` and `ylab`?  i might want add defaults for `title=` and `xlim=` and `ylim=` as well, so writing out every combination is not feasible?  thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Make your own custom wrapper to the `plot` function:

```
myplot <- function(x, y, xlab = 'mylabel', ylab = 'ylabel', ...){
  plot(x, y, xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, ...)
}


myfun <- 
  function( ... ){

    # myfun only passes `...` on to the plot function
    myplot(...)

  }
```

Now the following calls work as I think you want them to work:

```
myfun(1, 1)
myfun(1, 1,xlab = "new label" , ylab = "another label" )
```

**Solution 2**

You can also use `list(...)` and `do.call` in the following manner:

```
myfun <- 
  function( ... ){

    dots = list(...)

    # check whether needed defaults are supplied, if not, supply them.
    if ~grep('xlab', names(dots) ){
      dots$xlab = 'mylabel'
    }        
    if ~grep('ylab', names(dots) ){
      dots$ylab = 'ylabel'
    }


    # myfun only passes `...` on to the plot function
    do.call(plot, dots)

  }
```

Comment: exactly what i was looking for..thank you!  https://github.com/DjalmaPessoa/convey/commit/4dd0d2d2f36385423e9c03fc6cb2ed51e060fcf9